# Python library to display a web page on Mac

Tags: python, macos

Is there a Python library that will easily display a web page in a small window on Mac? I just want to display a web page when the user clicks a button, but without the user having to leave my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyQt has an integrated web browser in it.  So any app you make with PyQt can also include a browser window. PyQt is cross-platfrom so it should work on a mac as well.